# SwiftUI: Can't get the transition of a DetailView to a ZStack in the MainView to work

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, transition, z-index

I can't find the answer to this anywhere, hopefully one of you can help me out.

I have a MainView with some content. And with the press of a button I want to open a DetailView. I am using a ZStack to layer the DetailView on the top, filling the screen.

But with the following code I can't get it to work. The DetailView does not have a transition when it inserts and it stops at removal. I have tried with and without setting the zIndex manually, and a custom assymetricalTransition. Couldn't get that to work. Any solutions?

```
//MainView
@State var showDetail: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello MainWorld")
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    self.showDetail.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Show detail")
            }
        }


        if showDetail {
            ContentDetail(showDetail: $showDetail)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

And here is the DetailView:

```
//DetailView

@Binding var showDetail: Bool    

var body: some View {
    VStack (spacing: 25) {
        Text("Hello, DetailWorld!")

        Button(action: { withAnimation(.spring()) {
            self.showDetail.toggle()
            }

        }) {
            Text("Close")
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 50)


    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
           height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    .background(Color.yellow)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

}
```

The result of this code is this: 
[image]

I'm running Xcode 11.4.1 so implicit animations doesn't seem to work either. Really stuck here, hope one of you can help me out! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image: demo]

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var showDetail: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear // extend ZStack to all area
            VStack {
                Text("Hello MainWorld")
                Button(action: {
                        self.showDetail.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Show detail")
                }
            }

            if showDetail {
                DetailView(showDetail: $showDetail)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .animation(Animation.spring())  // one animation to transitions
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var showDetail: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 25) {
            Text("Hello, DetailWorld!")

            Button(action: {
                self.showDetail.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Close")
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 50)


        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // fill in container
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried this earlier, but with this solution the DetailCard immediately goes to the background and if I try to set it to the front manually with a zIndex(1), the app crashes. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Wood, I don't know what is a `DetailCard` - there is no such view in question materials. As you see in demo, DetailView is on top for both direction transitions, that's why I did not use zIndex, but, anyway, if you add in my code `DetailView(showDetail: $showDetail).transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom)).zIndex(1)` there will be no crash.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the DetailView, my bad. If you run that initial answer with Slow Animations or set the Color to .white instead of .clear, it's visible. With the .zIndex(1) modifier it works fine the first time you press the button but if you relatively quickly press it again, the app will crash.

Comment: Just FYI, Asperi's answer worked for me, as long as you set the zIndex as mentioned above in the comments.

Comment: If anyone else is experiencing the crash Wood is describing what fixed it for me was putting my higher Z index view above the other view in my `body` property.