# How do I prevent a sheet from darkening the view behind it in SwiftUI or remove the unnecessary padding?

Tags: swiftui

[image: SwiftUI sheet darkens the view behind it and leaves padding around the view]

When a sheet (modal) is presented, the view behind it shrinks and gets darker, resulting in a gray rectangle behind the sheet (see the bit inside the red box in the picture). How do I prevent the view in the background from getting darker, or get rid of the white padding around it when it gets shrunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default `.sheet` behavior.

With **SwiftUI 2.0** use full screen cover instead

```
@available(iOS 14.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
@available(macOS, unavailable)
extension View {

    /// Presents a modal view that covers as much of the screen as
    /// possible using the given item as a data source for the sheet's content.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - item: A binding to an optional source of truth for the cover
    ///     modal view. When representing a non-nil item, the system uses
    ///     `content` to create a modal representation of the item.
    ///     If the identity of `item` changes, the system will dismiss a
    ///     currently-presented modal view and replace it by a new modal view.
    ///   - onDismiss: A closure executed when the modal view dismisses.
    ///   - content: A closure returning the content of the modal view.
    public func fullScreenCover<Item, Content>(item: Binding<Item?>, onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> Content) -> some View where Item : Identifiable, Content : View


    /// Presents a modal view that covers as much of the screen as
    /// possible when a given condition is true.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - isPresented: A binding to whether the modal view is presented.
    ///   - onDismiss: A closure executed when the modal view dismisses.
    ///   - content: A closure returning the content of the modal view.
    public func fullScreenCover<Content>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View where Content : View

}
```

For **SwiftUI 1.0** you can use transition to show your view in full-screen, see example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446820/12299030

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! So are you saying there is no way to modify this default behavior unless the sheet is presented full-screen?