# how to navigate from Right to Left while using navigation link in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui, transition, swift5, right-to-left, swiftui-navigationlink

```
                    NavigationLink("", destination: login(),isActive: $goWhenTrue)
                 
                      
                    
                  
                    Button (action: { print("Button Tapped")}, label: {

                        Text("LogOut")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 340, height: 50)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                            .padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                
                                self.goWhenTrue = true
                                if ((UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Username") != nil)) {
                                    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Username")
                                         
                                }
                            }
              
                    })
                   
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 15, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
                    
                    Spacer()
```

I want to navigate from a logout page to main page  but the transition effect must be from Right to left  of the page
this is my log out code
can i do any modifications here to get that effect

Comment: When you log in to the application, do you navigate to the Home screen with NavigationLink or with .fullScreenCover?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446820/7129318) help?

Comment: i use navigation link

Comment: no that wont be usefull